# Math operations conditional statement

Tags: java, math, conditional-statements, statements

```
public class Eval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int operand1;
        char exp1;
        int operand2;

        if (args.length != 3 ) {
            System.err.println("*** Program needs 3 arguements***");
            System.err.println("Usage: java Eval int1 exp int2");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        operand1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        exp1 = args[1].charAt(0);

        operand2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);


        System.out.print(args[0] + args[1] + args[2] + "=");

        switch(exp1){
            case('-'):
                System.out.println(operand1 - operand2);
                break;
            case('+'):
                System.out.println(operand1 + operand2);
                break;
            case('/'):
                System.out.println(operand1 / operand2);
                break;
            case('*'):
                System.out.println(operand1 * operand2);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" Error.Invalid operator.");
        }
      }
    }
```

This is a program to do mathematical operations. Currently the program can do everything but multiply the integers, why does this happen? Furthermore, why is the (Usuage: java Eval) part necessary -- it doesn't work without it. Is there a way to avoid doing this? Lastly why are the args necessary. I'm sorry for so many questions, but I don't want to blindly write a program with no clear understanding of what I'm actually doing. Thank You very much for all the help and once again sorry for so many questions!

Comment: Frankly speaking, you are asking two different questions here. For what is `args` you can simply go through any basic Java tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? When you say that multiplication doesn't work, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the multiplication is not in Java, but the command line itself.  The `*` character is special on command lines, so escape it in the command line and you should be fine:

```
$ java Eval 6 * 9
*** Program needs 3 arguements***
Usage: java Eval int1 exp int2
$ java Eval 6 \* 9
6*9=54
```

The args are necessary here because Java takes the command line arguments and passes them to your program through the `main` parameter `args`.

You must say `java Eval` because you're really running the program `java` -- the JVM itself.  Its first argument is the class containing the `main` method to run.  All other command line arguments are passed to the `args` parameter of `main`.

The [Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) explains how command-line arguments work.

Comment: It appears that when using Windows Command Prompt, using single quotes is the only thing that works (that I've found); `\*` does not, but rather is expanded to all files in the `\ ` root folder.  The Java tutorial you linked at doesn't explain anything about wildcard expansion, by the way.  On Un*x-type systems, this isn't a Java issue, of course, since the shell processes the `*` before Java ever sees it.  P.S. I'm using the Java downloaded from Oracle, but other platforms may behave differently.

Comment: Thanks, also what would I need to do so if I add this statement                 if ( (args[1] == "/" ) && (args[2] == "0" ) ) {
   System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero");
  } else {                                              before the switch I only get the "cannot divide by zero and Exception in thread main

Comment: @user2827494 You can either test with `if` as you have it, or you can enclose the actual division in a try-catch block to catch the `ArithmeticException`.  I would go with testing the arguments with `if` so you can detect the case yourself.  But if you go with `if`, compare your `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with `==`.

Comment: @user2827494 If you go with `if`, please don't use string comparison to compare numbers.  `args[2] == "0"` or (better) `args[2].equals("0")` will not catch it if you enter `"00"` as one of the arguments, but the program will still try to divide by zero.  Instead wait until you call `parseInt` and then check `operand2 == 0`.